# Links works only in submenu

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to modify the following code becouse the links works only in a submenu , but i want to have some links in mainmenu too.

I found that when I use

```
$menuItems = $listItems.children(‘a.dropdown’);
```

instead of

```
$menuItems = $listItems.children( 'a' ),
```

*...links from the main menu work fine , but logically submenu does not open.*

Whole code:

```
var cbpHorizontalMenu = (function() {

var $listItems = $( '#cbp-hrmenu > ul > li' ),
    $menuItems = $listItems.children( 'a' ),
    $body = $( 'body' ),
    current = -1;

function init() {
    $menuItems.on( 'click', open );
    $listItems.on( 'click', function( event ) { event.stopPropagation(); } );
}

function open( event ) {

    if( current !== -1 ) {
        $listItems.eq( current ).removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
    }

    var $item = $( event.currentTarget ).parent( 'li' ),
        idx = $item.index();

    if( current === idx ) {
        $item.removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
        current = -1;
    }
    else {
        $item.addClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
        current = idx;
        $body.off( 'click' ).on( 'click', close );
    }

    return false;

}

function close( event ) {
    $listItems.eq( current ).removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
    current = -1;
}

return { init : init };
```

HTML:

```
            <div class="main">
            <nav id="cbp-hrmenu" class="cbp-hrmenu">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
    <li><a href="/PPC.php">O SPOLEČNOSTI</a></li>
    <li>
                    <a href="#">SLUŽBY</a>
                        <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                            <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">

                                <p>
                                     <div><ul><li class=""><a href="/socialni-site.php">SOCIÁLNÍ SÍTĚ</a></li></ul></div>
                                     <div><ul><li class=""><a href="/responzivni-web.php">RESPONZIVITA</a></li></ul></div>
                                     <div><ul><li class=""><a href="/tvorba-webu.php">TVORBA WEBU</a></li></ul></div>
                                     <div><ul><li class=""><a href="/seo-optimalizace.php">SEO OPTIMALIZACE</a></li></ul></div>
                                     <div><ul><li class=""><a href="/PPC.php">PPC</a></li></ul></div>





                            </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
                        </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->

                    </li></ul></nav>
```

Comment: you should put your html markup to your question

Comment: @user3273700 done